# Dynamic Query Error in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate, database-link

I am trying to execute this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_DYNAMIC 
AS
  tbl_list VARCHAR2(2000);
  DBLINK   VARCHAR2(100);
  V_SQL    VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  DBLINK := 'SOME_LINK';
  V_SQL := 'SELECT table_name,table_owner FROM dba_tab_modifications@:DB_LINK';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL USING DBLINK;

  COMMIT;

  Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE (TBL_LIST);
END;
```

But When I execute the stored procedure I get the error:

```
ORA-01729: database link name expected
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.SP_DYNAMIC"
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Can somebody help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because you can't use a bind variable as the dblink. You get the same error when running the following:

`select * from dual@:dblink;`

If you absolutely must use dynamic sql, you'd have to concatenate the dblink name into the statement - but you'll have to be aware that you're now open to SQL Injection:

`V_SQL :=  'SELECT table_name,table_owner FROM dba_tab_modifications@'||DB_LINK;`

Comment: Fuether to this answer... you can  use DMBS_ASSERT.QUALIFIED_SQL_NAME on the result of  dba_tab_modifications@'||DB_LINK; " part of the string in order to minimise the sql injection vulnerability

Comment: Thanks, @James - that's something I was unaware of.